# node.js express + aws elb - redirect from http to https not working

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-elb

I know that this has already been asked and answered here but still no solution has worked for me. Here is the app.js:

```
   var express  = require('express');
   var app      = express();

   app.all(function(req, res, next){
           if((!req.secure) && (req.get('X-Forwarded-Proto') !== 'https'))
           {
                console.log (req.get('Host'));
                console.log("not secure");
                res.redirect('https://' + req.get('Host') + req.url);
           }
           else{
           console.log("secure");
           next();
          }
      }
   );

   app.use(express.static('./server/static/'));
   app.listen(8080);
```

I have tried using app.use as well but still it doesn't work.
We are using AWS ELB and here are the listeners:

LB Protocol | LB Port | Instance Protocol |Instance Port

HTTPS       |    443   |    HTTP              |    8080
HTTP        |    80      | HTTP              | 8080

As mentioned in other posts, I do not see 'x-forwarded-proto' in my request headers. I believe the listeners have been configured correctly so that they should have included 'x-forwarded' headers but that's not the case.

When I try hitting the dns without https, it doesn't get redirected to https.
However, both http and https urls work fine individually.

Please help me figuring out what I am missing or if any more information needs to be provided.

Comment: @robertklep can I please ask you to take a look on this? sorry for this desperate call for help but I have seen your answers and comments on such posts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to check for both 'X-Forwarded-Proto' and 'x-forwarded-proto' (lowercase). Also, the request will never be secure inside your application, so you should also remove the req.secure check. The final code should look something like this:

```
function forceHttps(req, res, next) {
    const xfp =
    req.headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"] || req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"];
    if (xfp === "http") {
        const secureUrl = `https://${req.headers.hostname}${req.url}`;
        res.redirect(301, secureUrl);
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
```

We use this code for our Express application behind Elastic Load Balancer, and it works fine. We even created a small NPM package that handles this, if you don't want to write the middleware yourself:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@crystallize/elasticloadbalancer-express-force-https

Install

```
npm i --save @crystallize/elasticloadbalancer-express-force-https
```

Usage

```
const express = require('express');
const forceHttps = require('@crystallize/elasticloadbalancer-express-force-https');
const server = express();
server.use(forceHttps());
```

More information in our blog post about this:
https://snowball.digital/blog/force-https-behind-elastic-load-balancer-on-a-nodejs-application